# Django Rest Framework - Test Client Post list of integers

Tags: python, django, api, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I'm doing an app using django and I want to unit test my viewsets.

I can test almost everything but, everytime I send an integer or a list to the viewset via API Client, in the viewset, the integer is converted to a string, therefore, that's a big fail for me :(

**Example** - test file:

```
body = {
    "age": 60
}
client = APIClient()
res = client.post(url, body, **headers, type='json')
```

In the ViewSet: **request.data**

```
{
    "age" "60"
}
```

Comment: If you are using django, then why dont you go for django testcases?

Comment: change `type='json'` to `format='json'` and try again

Comment: I changed but it's still the same.

Answer (score 5):

This works:

```
client.post(url, json.dumps(body), **headers, format='json', content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: Update: you have to choose between `format` and `content_type` or else you'll hit the following error: `AssertionError: You may not set both format and content_type.`